# How htmx can access data from an event?

Tags: django, htmx

I have a view

```
def tag_delete(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        tag_name = request.POST.get("tag")
        tag = Tag.objects.get(name=tag_name)
        tag.delete()

        response = HttpResponse(status=204, headers={'HX-Trigger': json.dumps({
                "taglistchangeddelete": {"tag": tag_name}
            })})
                  
        return response
```

When the user clicks a button to delete a tag, this view is called. This view works fine. But the problem start because i have a session variable that contains a list of selected tags. If the tag that has been deleted is in this list, it should be removed from there. So, I created another view to handle this deletion:

```
def process_tags_deleted(request, tag):   

    selected_tags = request.session['selected_tags']    
    if tag in selected_tags:
        selected_tags.remove(tag)

    request.session['selected_tags'] = selected_tags
    
    #The rendered template will show the user their selected tags 
    response = render(request, 'espace/tags_selected.html', {
             'selected_tags': selected_tags,
          })  

    return response
```

To call the process_tag_deleted function, I created an HTMX get request within a random div in the template:

```
<div hx-get={% url 'process_tags_deleted' %}
         hx-vals='{"tag": evt.detail.tag}'
         hx-target="#tags_selected"
         hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'
         hx-trigger="taglistchangeddelete">
    </div>
```

I'm pretty sure that the problem lies in the hx-vals. I can't retrieve the 'tag' value that comes from the event "taglistchangeddelete". It gives a syntax HTMX error in the console:

```
htmx:syntax:error
b @ htmx.min.js:1
function b(e) {
      if (console.error) {
        console.error(e) #ERROR
      } else if (console.log) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", e)
      }
    }
```

What does this error mean? And how to handle my task? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: If this is your exact code, you're missing quotes around `process_tags_deleted` url in the last div. But I don't see why this needs to be in two seperate views, what's happening when you delete from session inside `tag_delete`?

Comment: Hi, McPherson, thanks for your response. I used single quotes instead of double quotes. I haven't attempted deletion within the 'tag_delete' function, but this issue extends beyond that. I also have a view for editing tags, so the tags in the 'selected_tags' list need to be updated. Additionally, I have a list of checkboxes with tag names that require modification. Employing events to manage these various DOM elements seemed like a more efficient approach, but I appreciate the advice. However, I still need guidance on how to utilize event data in HTMX. Can you provide any insights on this?

Comment: Yes, I could address this issue with just one view. However, my main focus was on discovering a method to extract data from an event in HTMX. Thank you for your assistance! If you have any suggestions on how to accomplish this, I would greatly appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructure the `HttpResponse` in `tag_delete`:

```
def tag_delete(request):
    ... 
    response = HttpResponse(status=204)
    response["Hx-Trigger"] = json.dumps({"taglistchangeddelete": tag_name})
    return response
```

Then to access the response:

```
<div hx-get="{% url 'process_tags_deleted' %}" 
     hx-vals='js:{"tag": event.detail.value}'
     hx-target="#tags_selected"
     hx-trigger="taglistchangeddelete from:body">
</div>
```

**Note**

GET requests don't need `csrf_token`.

Comment: Hi, thanks (again) for the help. When I first tried the solution, it didn't work. Then I realized that the process_tags_deleted(request, tag) function required a tag parameter, and that was the issue. After changing that, the problem was solved. Thanks, man, you're a lifesaver! When my website is done, I'll show it to you. It'll probably be completed in July. It'll be called quaac.com. It will be an open-source project where people can submit questions, solve them, and help each other out, like you're doing. Ty !!!!